# DVWA - Odd command injection behaviour (High)

Tags: professional-education, dvwa

After completing the OS Command Injection level on High, I was delving a little deeper so I could write it up. It seems that while the solution works on the web app the same command errors on the linux terminal.

DVWA command for the High level

```
127.0.0.1|  |cat /etc/passwd
```

This works. Doesn't output the ping result but prints to screen the contents of /etc/passwd

If I use the exact same command on my linux terminal it errors. Code used to mimic the web application

```
ping -c 3 127.0.0.1|  |cat /etc/passwd
```

I receive the error

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `|'
```

If I remove the spaces the command works as expected. I can't explain why the shell_exec PHP command passes the command to the OS, the OS runs it and displays the result, yet the direct approach errors. Technically the DVWA command shouldn't work?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but /etc/passwd is generally considered public information on a Linux system, as one of its purposes is to map from numeric user IDs to plain-text usernames (useful for example in file listings).

Answer (score 1):

It's caused by the deliberately faulty blacklist. Pipe followed by space gets replaced with an empty string. The second pipe is immediately followed by a c and thus does not match the blacklist and hence slips through. The first pipe and space are redundant. Ip|cat should also work, as does ip%0acat and ip%26%26cat.

Answer (score 0):

DVWA Command Injection Hign file in Blacklist

// Set blacklist
$substitutions = array(
    '&'  => '',
    ';'  => '',
    '| ' => '',
    '-'  => '',
    '$'  => '',
    '('  => '',
    ')'  => '',
    '`'  => '',
    '||' => '',
);

- This is "&&" not in blacklist.
- This is using "&&";
  ping -c4 127.0.0.1 && echo "Ok!"

Comment: That command doesn't work on version 1.10. Only the double pipes with two spaces works it seems.